# how rotate image of the arrow and will draw in the center of another image

Tags: android, rotation, translate-animation

```
 canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawBitmap(dial, 0, 0, new Paint());

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(80);
        matrix.preTranslate(-arrow.getWidth() / 2, -arrow.getHeight());
        matrix.postTranslate(arrow.getWidth() / 2, arrow.getHeight());

        Bitmap bb = Bitmap.createBitmap(arrow, 0, 0, arrow.getWidth(), arrow.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bb, centerXY - bb.getWidth() / 2, 0, new Paint());
```

I searched and read many post about "how rotate a image around center in android". But my code is does not work. What am I doing wrong? You will see result by screenshot:

[image: http://s58.radikal.ru/i161/1305/aa/b855c2ed8af6.jpg]

Comment: have a look at my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384186/calculate-new-positon-of-rectangle-corners-based-on-angle